# Percentage on y axis of scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, percentage, yaxis

Hi I am trying to change the y-axis to have percentage after each number so [20%,30%, 40%, 50%, 60%]. If there is also a way to do this for the x-axis please share. Thank you! In addition the legends aren't appearing for some reason. [image]

```
dose  <- c(20, 30, 40, 45, 60)
drugA <- c(16, 20, 27, 40, 60)
drugB <- c(15, 18, 25, 31, 40)


plot( dose, drugA, col='blue', lty=1)
points( dose, drugB, col='red', lty=2)
legend(1, 95, legend=c("Drug A", "Drug B"),
       col=c("blue", "red"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
grid( lty=1 )
```

I am new to R so sorry if this is a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

In base R plotting, you have to generally turn off the default and then generate a new axis, like:

```
## note xaxt="n" suppressing the y axis
plot(dose, drugA, col='blue', lty=1, xaxt="n")
points(dose, drugB, col='red', lty=2)
legend(1, 95, legend=c("Drug A", "Drug B"),
       col=c("blue", "red"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
grid(lty=1)
## add a new axis
axis(1, at=axTicks(1), labels=paste0(axTicks(1), "%"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Is there any reason why my legends are not appearing?

Comment: The `legend` is at x=1, y-95 - that is outside the range of your axes. Try `legend("topleft", ...` instead of specifying the points manually. Also change the order so that the grid lines come after the legend.